# How can I debug who's overwriting my jQuery ajax behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

I'm serving a script that people can embed on their webpages (think FB like or Tweet this button).

On one host page I noticed some really strange behavior: My script is executing XHR `POST` requests using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: myUrl
    , data: data
    , method: 'POST'
    , beforeSend: function(xhr){
       xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Some-Header', someValue);
    }
});
```

On the page in question this will perform a GET request instead. The page is quite a mess, loading about 4 different versions of jQuery and also using Prototype 1.6. My guess would be that someone somewhere is overwriting something that turns every XHR into a `GET` request (There's not a single `POST` leaving the site in question when I inspect the network activity, also from other 3rd party scripts).

Trouble is I have no idea how to debug this as reading tons and tons of minified code won't be of too much help.

Is there a feasible way to do debug this? Can I somehow force detect if jQuery has been altered before my script uses it? Should I ship my own version of `$.post` instead?

Comment: How about injecting `console.log` into dev `jQuery` version and then replacing one of your `jQuery` libraries on the page with the modified one? You can replace lib without touching your backend by using proxies, like `Fiddler2`.

Comment: Look at the network tab, initiator column in Chrome dev tools. It gives you script name and line number.

Answer (score 1):

Few tips:

- In Google Chrome's developer tools, Network Tab, look at the initiator column. For XHR, it logs the filename and line number on which the request was created.
- In Google Chrome's developer tools, Sources Tab, right sidebar, open the **DOM Breakpoints** collapsible group. Click on the `+` icon and enter the URL in question. When an XHR for that URL is executed, Chrome will pause in debugger. Look at the stack trace for hints.

Comment: The problem is that I have no trouble understanding what my script does and what initiates my calls, but what is altering its behavior.

Comment: The stack trace should tell you if it was your script or some other script that causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to protect from intentional messing with your code, or just untidy pages that have lots of different stuff loaded and interfere with your scripts?

If second, just use [jQuery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and assign jQuery default variable to some unique name like:

```
jQuery_my_script=$.noConflict(true);
```

and then use it instead of $. 
Simple and elegant solution, no need for debuging.

Comment: You can always load .src version of jQuery. Then debuging may give you some hints on what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using,getEventListeners(document) in any of the dev tools. This method will return all the events which are bound to the document. Check whether some binding has been done which disturbs your flow.

You can also set the "global" attribute of this request to false which will by pass the global changes if any.http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/